# boost::thread attributes setting (call) stack size

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, stack

I'm getting crashes in my multi-threaded application which I suspect to be stack overflows (should be a nice site to ask this question) because I'm doing some pretty deep recursion and the crash doesn't happen with smaller orders of the problem. I'm using boost::thread. It offers the possibillity to set the stack size (in advance) via an attribute:

```
boost::thread::attributes l_ThreadAttributes;
l_ThreadAttributes.set_stack_size(8000000);
boost::thread l_MyThread(l_ThreadAttributes, l_MyFunctor);
```

I'm not very convinced that this actually works. If I ask the current stack size via the same attribute "get_stack_size()" I get 0. Does anyone have experience with it (I'm working on Windows 7 32-bit, Visual Studio 9 2008, boost_1_54_0)? Furthermore, how would this relate to the value I would put in the linker settings (Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size -> 8000000 for instance)?

Is there a convenient way to check how much stack I have left at runtime (in the current thread)? The handy stackavail() function that used to be in malloc.h and/or stdlib.h seems to have vanished.

Thanks in advance, 
Daniel Dekkers

Comment: On the old days of windows programming, the stack size was fixed in the executable and could not "grow" at runtime; I am not sure if something has changed since then, but your description makes me guess that it did not.

Comment: I'm not sure. What I've read is that it is not too bad to have a large call stack size reserved because the memory is only allocated when needed. But I'm not sure about the other way around, an overflow, when you have too little memory reserved. But the boost::thread::attribute does exist. Also read that on Windows 1 MB is standard, on Linux 8 MB is standard. I'm also using CMake as a build tool and it, until very recently, set the call stack on 10 MB automatically for Windows. All combined, I guess it still is a real issue.

Comment: So,.. it wasn't a stack overflow after all. The problem was in try_join_for(timeout) in boost::tread. You can't pass a timeout value of 0 because then, once every million times, it blocks. -sigh-